# Как лучше устроить поиск по годам?

Tags: sql, node.js

У меня есть веб приложение с историями и я хочу туда заделать поиск по годам. Например, одна история произошла в 2007-2008 и я хочу найти истории за 2006-2008 и тут выдаёт мне эту историю. И как это грамотно сделать?

Comment: нам с неба взять, что именно за приложение, код этого приложения и т.д.?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всё полностью зависит от того, что раздражает пользователей во время использования приложения, и вас в моменты внесения изменений в его код.

Судя по вопросу - сейчас вы ещё только прорабатываете идею. Пока не появится хотя бы готового прототипа приложения, которое можно взять и запустить - не может быть никаких "грамотно сделать".

Пока и банальное sql-условие вроде `[date] BETWEEN @start AND @end` сойдет.

Когда запустите своё приложение - вы станете первым его пользователем: вот тут то вас и начнет что-то раздражать в его работе - например, тот же "медленный вывод истории" - тогда и прийдется придумывать и искать более "грамотные решения".

Что в программировании, что в жизни не существует "лучших практик применимых в любых ситуациях". Любое решение, которое выполняет поставленную задачу и не раздражает пользователя - как раз и является "грамотным".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, действительно отличное решение